# Android emulator for Ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't know much more about Ubuntu yet, I am looking for android emulator for my Ubuntu14. If any there could you please let me know (with download and installation instructions)

Comment: Note that there's no Ubuntu 14. I assume you mean 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an emulator, but you can run an Android OS in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox.  Depending what your end goal is, this may be all you need.

You can download an Android ISO from here:

http://www.android-x86.org/download

Instructions can be found here:

https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/virtualbox/